# My application can not work with an SD card formatted by using the exFAT format

Tags: android

My application can not work with an SD card formatted by using the exFAT format. Can only application of producer by phone or Google itself use SD card with exFAT format? .. Where is the problem? If you use a FAT formatted so everything works.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DIRECTORY);
```

When you open `DOCUMENT TREE` missing SD card formatted using exFAT and SD card with Fat format is visible on `DOCUMENT TREE` and works good. Phone producer or Google may not force the user for permission to `DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Answer (score 0):

If `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` works with FAT-formatted removable media, and it does not work with exFAT-formatted removable media, the problem is not with your app. If anything, the problem may be with the device.

I am not aware that Android is advertised as supporting exFAT. If it is supported at all, I would expect that support to vary by Android OS version and perhaps by manufacturer/device.

For example, I just formatted a microSD card with exFAT and put it in a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (SM-N900) running Android 5.0. I have no problems using `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` with that microSD card.

Comment: Thanks. I understand only a pity that here is a lot of those users who have a similar phone in which it does not work, because new sd cards > 32 are from the manufacturer usually formatted with exFAT format.

Comment: @MichalBukáček: Perhaps your device does not support cards of that size.